# Howto import operators in swi-prolog?

Tags: module, prolog, swi-prolog

I have the following file:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

isPowTwo(N) :- N #> 0, N #= 2^_.
```

Everything works fine:

```
?- [importTest].
%     library(pairs) compiled into pairs 0.00 sec, 22 clauses
%    library(lists) compiled into lists 0.01 sec, 122 clauses
%    library(occurs) compiled into occurs 0.00 sec, 14 clauses
%   library(apply_macros) compiled into apply_macros 0.01 sec, 168 clauses
%   library(assoc) compiled into assoc 0.01 sec, 103 clauses
%  library(clpfd) compiled into clpfd 0.15 sec, 2,808 clauses
% importTest compiled 0.16 sec, 2,813 clauses
true.
```

Now I want to import just the two used operators:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd), [(#>)/2, (#=)/2]).

isPowTwo(N) :- N #> 0, N #= 2^_.
```

And it does not work:

```
?- [importTest].
%     library(pairs) compiled into pairs 0.00 sec, 22 clauses
%    library(lists) compiled into lists 0.01 sec, 122 clauses
%    library(occurs) compiled into occurs 0.00 sec, 14 clauses
%   library(apply_macros) compiled into apply_macros 0.01 sec, 168 clauses
%   library(assoc) compiled into assoc 0.01 sec, 103 clauses
%  library(clpfd) compiled into clpfd 0.16 sec, 2,808 clauses
ERROR: .../importTest.pl:3:17: Syntax error: Operator expected
% importTest compiled 0.16 sec, 2,812 clauses
true.

?- isPowTwo(1).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: isPowTwo/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Leaving the parentheses around `#>` and `#=` makes no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `use_module/2` directive (hence the `Syntax error: Operator expected` error messages). You can correct it by writing:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd), [(#>)/2, (#=)/2]).
```

But you will also need to import the corresponding operators for use in the definition of your `isPowTwo/1` predicate:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd), [(#>)/2, (#=)/2, op(700,xfx,(#>)), op(700,xfx,(#=))]).
```

Comment: The idea was that you can import operators by pattern, as in `op(_,_,#>)`, so you do not need to repeat the priority.  This was broken.  Pushed a fix for this, so it should work in 7.3.27.